# How to change the row to column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have a table like below:

```
Name        Org
aaaa        bbb 
aaaa        bbbb 
aaaa        bbbbb
bbbb        cccc
```

How can I use oracle sql change to the format below

```
Name   Org1       Org2       Org3
aaaa   bbb        bbbb       bbbbb
bbbb   cccc
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Are you going to have a limited number of orgs for each name?

Comment: Oracle 11 yes,. I think 5 is the most orgs each name can have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can get the result.  Both versions that I show use `row_number()` to help convert the rows into columns.

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select 
  name,
  max(case when seq = 1 then org end) org1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then org end) org2,
  max(case when seq = 3 then org end) org3,
  max(case when seq = 4 then org end) org4,
  max(case when seq = 5 then org end) org5
from
(
  select name, org,
    row_number() over(partition by name
                      order by org) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/974db/6).  Or since you are using Oracle 11g, you can use the PIVOT function to convert the rows into columns:

```
select name,
  Org1,
  Org2,
  Org3,
  Org4,
  Org5
from
(
  select name, org,
    row_number() over(partition by name
                      order by org) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(org)
  for seq in ('1' as Org1, '2' as Org2, 
              '3' as Org3, '4' as Org4, 
              '5' as Org5)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/974db/6). Both give a result:

```
| NAME | ORG1 |   ORG2 |   ORG3 |   ORG4 |   ORG5 |
| aaaa |  bbb |   bbbb |  bbbbb | (null) | (null) |
| bbbb | cccc | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` to achieve this.

Something like [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm):-

```
select *
from
  (select fk_department
   from employee)
   pivot
    (count(fk_department)
      for fk_department in ('INT', 'WEL', 'CEN', 'POL'));
```

Comment: I don't know how many departments aaaa has. What should I use in "fk_department in ('INT', 'WEL', 'CEN', 'POL'))"? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is just an example not the actual query which you have to use. The explanation of this is explained in the link which I have shared!!!